# Handling Multi browser support in spec for Galen Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, galen

I am using [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com/) for UI testing for my application. The issue I am facing is that the CSS value for the font-family varies between browsers. And if I add the check for 1 value the specs fails for the other browsers. I can write different specs for differnt browsers, but I want to avoid that.

The list below shows the different values for the CSS property "font-family".

- Firefox = "Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif,sans-serif"
- Chrome = "Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif, sans-serif"
- IE   = "helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif,sans-serif"

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a custom rules (http://galenframework.com/docs/reference-galen-spec-language-guide/#CustomRules) for that. I didn't tried it, but maybe you can get the browser name to and wrap all the browser specific stuff in a custom rule

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried creating a JS script and tried using it as a rule but failed due to this know bug on windows. This bug causes failure in loading the js script from spec file. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/galen-framework/spec/galen-framework/ulw5D_Dd8UA/Iqqo6-j1BQAJ

Comment: if you provide me the source code I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use something like below:

```html
@set
    fontlist    "(Helvetica|Arial|Verdana|sans-serif|helvetica|arial|verdana)"
= Check value of the object =
    objectname:
      css font-family matches ${fontlist}
```

Another way, if you want to check exact value:

```html
= Check value of the object =
objectname:
  @on ie
   css font-family is "helvetica,arial,verdana,sans-serif,sans-serif" 
  @on firefox
   css font-family is "Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif,sans-serif"
  @on chrome
   css font-family is "Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif, sans-serif"
```